how to use dynamic SQL in Application Express
I'm trying to figure out how to use dynamic SQL in Application Express.
I have a field called SQL TEXT where users will be able to pass some commands, like SELECT, for example.
And below, there is a display only field called OUTPUT, which, as the name says, is the output.
However, when I pass:
    select * from table1

This gives me an error:
    Error executing: ORA-00932: inconsistent data types: expected - but obtained -

However, when I pass a column from this table, the query returns the column correctly.enter image description here
I expected that select * from would bring me all the data in the table.

First question you have to ask is... do you really need it AND do you really want it. The beauty of APEX is that data is presented to users with report that are purposely written. Users cannot see data that there is no report on. Administrators should use SQL Workshop or Scripts to perform administrative tasks. In mostt cases there should not be a need for an application like the one you're describing. If you do want to go down that route, then here are a couple of guidelines and thing to keep in mind:
Basically this is just a form an report. But instead of getting the information from a table with a fixed number of known columns the information comes from an unknown source with an unknown number of columns that are of unknown data type.
That means that the columns of the report cannot be defined in APEX, they have to be generated at runtime. There are a lot of pieces to this challenge:

generate the select. Use a source type of "PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query". The query will have to be cleaned up (substr any CLOB columns, ingnore BLOB columns, ignore nested columns, etc etc). The select will also have to be checked for syntax so only SELECT statements are allowed (no delete, no update, no pl/sql anonymous blocks)
If the number of columns is dynamic then this can only be done using a classic report. Alternatively, always select 20 or 50 columns from a collection that stores the result of your sql. In that case you can use an interactive report.
Parse the statement using DBMS_SQL.PARSE to validate syntax.
Create a number of page items, one for each column to get the column headers. Column names can be found using DBMS_SQL.describe_columns

This is... a lot of work.

The issue here is to create a screen where you can perform DML and DLL operations without being caught by the audit.
Passing the application user in the log.
This is the activity that was requested of me, so I am doing it.

Sure. I've given you the steps on how to do this for executing sql.

The error ORA-00932: inconsistent data types occurs when Oracle Database encounters a mismatch in expected data types during execution. The issue arises with the SELECT * query in Oracle Application Express (APEX) when the SQL TEXT field is dynamic.
Try use DBMS_SQL for Dynamic Queries.
Another test you can do to identify the column is to select COLUMN from table until you find the column with the problem in the data.
